# How to leverage designer when using a ViewModel first approach and composition

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have some xaml like:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="MyContent" />
```

and then on my ViewModel there is, of course, a MyContent property which references a ViewModel.  Then Caliburn does its compositional magic.

This is great, but in design time I can't see the composition.  I see 'most' people raving about the view model first approach, but I'm a little baffled as to whether there's a way to leverage the designer when doing this that I haven't yet realized or do all the vm first people just live with the fact that they have to run the application to see what it's going to look like?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462040/what-is-a-viewmodellocator-and-what-are-its-pros-cons-compared-to-datatemplates.

Comment: If you're using CM use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107635/how-to-use-designinstance-with-caliburn-micro